# Matlab cell2mat with different data types

Tags: matlab

When I import data from a database, I receive it as a cell. One row of the cell contains double values (such as 0.3421 0.5545 0.9199) and another row contains only int32 values (1 1 0). 
When I want to transform the whole cell with cell2mat, I get a mismatch error. If I use cell2mat on each row separately, I receive one matrix as double and one as int32. Is there a function being able to transform the whole cell to a matrix in double?

EDIT: I do not know beforehand which row is int32 and which is double, so it is not necessarily row 1 and 2. There are >50 rows

Comment: You can convert the second row to `double` and then concatenate: `c = {3.2; int32(5)}; result = [cell2mat(c(1,:)); double(cell2mat(c(2,:)))]`

Comment: Sorry, I now notice my description is incomplete. I do not know beforehand which row is in32 and which is double, so it is not necessarily row 1 and 2

Comment: Then convert both to `double`: `result = [double(cell2mat(c(1,:))); double(cell2mat(c(2,:)))]`

Comment: Or convert all values to doubles before calling `cell2mat` using `cellfun`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cellfun to cast all data to doubles before using cell2mat:

```
a={int16(round(100*rand(100,1))), int32(round(100*rand(100,1)))}

b = cellfun(@double, a, 'uni', false);

cell2mat(b)
```